# MSTest some tests ignored on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, mstest, nant

I´ve a nant build which compiles the project and then run mstests tests.

When I run the build locally, 68 tests are being run, but on jenkins, the same build runs only 48 tests.

In both cases, I´m using the same nant tasks (compile test), and have the exact same versions of both mstest (Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1), msbuild(4.0.30319.18408) and nant (0.92)

```
 <target name="compile">
    <exec program="${MSBuildPath}">
      <arg line='"${SolutionFile}"' />
      <arg line="/property:Configuration=Release" />
      <arg value="/target:Rebuild" />
      <arg value="/verbosity:normal" />
      <arg value="/nologo" />
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="test">
    <delete file="TestResults.trx"/>
    <if propertyexists="MsTestPath">
      <exec program="${MsTestPath}">
        <arg line="/testcontainer:${TestPath}" />
        <arg line="/testsettings:${TestSettingsPath}" />
        <arg line="/resultsfile:TestResults.trx" />
      </exec>
    </if>
    <ifnot propertyexists="MsTestPath">
      <exec program="MsTest.exe">
        <arg line="/testcontainer:${TestPath}" />
        <arg line="/testsettings:${TestSettingsPath}" />
        <arg line="/resultsfile:TestResults.trx" />
      </exec>
    </ifnot>

  </target>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: No clues in the results file? You mean MSTest not Nunit

Comment: thanks fixed the description.

Will try to look at these next week

Comment: @KMoraz found it to be using "release" mode instead of "debug".

Now my question would be, why would some tests be ignored on the "release" mode, but at least I have a new point to search